# Docker: JACK server is not running

Tags: audio, docker, ros, pulseaudio, jack

I'm running a host of docker containers with ROS, for controlling a robot. One of the container has to play some audio files through the `sound_play` package. However it returns the error

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory  
Cannot connect to server request channel  
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

I am able to `aplay` the audio (.wav) files from inside the container, my sound cards are definitely recognized, and I have also tried running the container in privileged mode. I have also tried to install `jackd` separately in the container and start a jack server, but get the error

```
Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory).  
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Is my understanding of the problem even correct? If so, how can I get jack server to start inside the container?

Comment: How do you launch your docker container ?

Comment: I use docker-compose, giving /dev/snd:/dev/snd mapping in devices, and have also tried running it independently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by installing `jackd1` instead of `jackd2` since apparently, jackd2 needs real time priorities which I was not able to provide to the docker container. `jackd1` did the trick though.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y jackd1
```

Run command:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged=true --device=/dev/snd:/dev/snd myContainerName jackd -R -d alsa -d hw:1
```

This will start a jack server in your container. The `sound_play` node worked fine after that.

Partial credits to http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=33530

Comment: For what I see this seems related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13983 maybe you could try again with jackd2 once it's fixed

Comment: Have subscribed to the issue, will try the fix when it's released and update here. Thanks!